# What's the NSTokenField designated initialiser?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstokenfield

I'm trying to subclass `NSTokenField` and I need to setup some ivars during initialisation but I can't work which initialiser I have to override. The documentation doesn't say anything about the designated initialisers of `NSTokenField` or `NSTextField` which the token field inherits from.

I tried overriding `-initWithFrame:` and `-init:` but they don't get called either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be either `initWithFrame:`, if you create the text field in your code, or `initWithCoder:` if the field is created in an XIB (Interface Builder) file.

This is because `NSTokenField` inherits from `NSView`, which conforms to the `NCoding` protocol. So this is also valid for other objects inheriting from `NSView`.

So basically, you should override both in a subclass:

```
- ( id )initWithFrame: ( NSRect )frame;
- ( id )initWithCoder: ( NSCoder * )decoder;
```

Comment: Thanks `-initWithCoder:` did the job.